# Kenmore dishwasher will not drain after the end of its cycle

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Kenmore dishwasher  model number 665.13293K113.  It runs a full cycle but will not empty out the water.

I took the hose apart ran, water through it, and it works fine.

I disconnected the pump and ran it and it seems to spin fine. I also ran the pump with the hose disconnected from the sink and it emptied fine.

Once I plug it back into the sink it does not push the water all the way up. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: The beauty of Kenmore is that you can get information about it from Sears.    Might want to try to talk to a tech and find out if this is user-fixable.

Comment: Could the water be siphoning back from the disposal? This can occur if the vacuum break is plugged and water doesn't drain out of the disposal quickly enough.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

If it pumps fine without the drain hose attached, then you have a plug in the drain. Make sure your sink drain is clear. Make sure the port in the drain pipe that the dishwasher hose attaches to it clear. If the dishwasher works fine disconnectes, then it is 99% of the time a drain issue under the sink. Not enough air is being introduced to "suck" the water down the drain.